# Immediate validation and editingFinished signal

Tags: qt4

I want to do immediate validation of my edit lines. I want to tell the user immediately after he left the edit line field that the value he entered is maybe incorrect.

So I connect the line edit with editingFinished() signal. However the problem is that the signal is not emitted when I click outside of the line edit, for example when I just click on the dialog. It is emitted when I click on some other line edit on the dialog. So I am looking for signal that is emitted everytime I click outside the edit line. How can I achieve this ?

```
connect(mLineEdit, SIGNAL(editingFinished()), this, SLOT(Validate()))

MyDlg::Validate()
{
     QString text = mLineEdit->text();
     bool isValid = check_if_valid(text);
     if(!isValid)
         // set the color of edit line to be red        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, consider using a [`QValidator`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html) implementation with your line edit to perform validation ([`QIntValidator`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qintvalidator.html), [`QDoubleValidator`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdoublevalidator.html), or [`QRegExpValidator`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qregexpvalidator.html)).  You can install the validator using [`QLineEdit::setValidator(QValidator*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#setValidator).  If one of these validators doesn't work for you, it's probably wise to look into writing your own validator by subclassing `QValidator` and providing an implementation of `validate`, then installing your own custom validator on the line edit.

Failing all of that, you can proceed as you have above, but you'll need to listen to either the `textChanged(const QString&)` signal or the `textEdited(const QString&)` signal (the former is emitted even when the line edit text is changed programatically, whereas the latter is not).